# Get checked item on select form - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

Im learning javascript and I have this function:

```
   function getRadioCity() {
    for (index=0; index < document.form_data2.ciudades.length; index++) {
        if (document.form_data2.ciudades[index].checked) {
            var radioValue =form_data2.ciudades[index].value;
             return parseInt(radioValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The function works fine but what if i have a select form instead radio?

For example:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
<form name="form_data2" id="form_data2"> <br>

<select name="ciudades" id="ciudades">
<option value="33">Armenia</option>
<option value="34">Cartagena</option>
</select>
 <input value="Enviar" id="btn_enviar" href="javascript:toggle() </input> <br /> <br />         <label id=" mensaje2="" type="button"> </form>
  <div id="resultado2"></div>
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Ill tried the same thing but doenst work..

edit:

I tried to make something like this:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btn_enviar').click(function(){

  if( validaSelect( 'ciudades','ciudades' ) == false) return false;


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url :'upload2.php',
        data: $('#form_data2').serialize(),
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#mensaje2').html('Enviando datos...');
        },
        success: function (data){
                $('#mensaje2').html('Datos enviados correctamente.');
                $('#resultado2').html(data);    
        },
        complete: function(){
             $('#form_data2').slideUp();
             $('#resultado2').slideDown();
              $('#content2').show();
              $('#flecha2').show();
             var num2 = getRadioCity();
        if (num2==1){
             $('#armenia').show();

        } 
         if (num2==2){
             $('#cartagena').show();
             alert("cartagena");

        } 



        }
    });

}); 


       });
```

basically get the value depending on the select and display a div or other

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#Get_information_about_the_selected_option

Comment: The fact that you're using jQuery makes this question even simpler to answer - why didn't you mention it before? Again RTFD: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value of `select` using `selectedIndex`.

```
document.getElementById("ciudades").onchange = function() {
    alert(this.selectedIndex);
}
```

Each option has its own number identifying itself. In the case of a `select` element, the first option has a `selectedIndex` of 0 and the second has a `selectedIndex` of 1 and so on. From this you can tell which `option` is selected.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnkx6/).

Try this:

```
var num2 = document.getElementById("ciudades").selectedIndex;
if (num2==0){
     $('#armenia').show();
} 
if (num2==1){
     $('#cartagena').show();
     alert("cartagena");
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to make works this on my function until sucess.